# Ansible: Run an async task, if it fails: run a cleanup tasks and retry the first task for x times

Tags: ansible

I would like to create a program flow similar to this:

```
- name: Clone git repository
  block:
  - git:
      repo: "{{ project_gitlab_repository }}"
      dest: "{{ project_build_path }}"
    async: 120
    poll: 5
  rescue:
  - file:
      path: "{{ project_build_path }}"
      state: absent
  - ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false 
  retries: 3
```

1. Attempt an async task
2. Should it fail, run a cleanup task. (in this case, delete the destination folder)
3. Go back to step 1 (for x times)

The code above does not work, it seems that you can' retry blocks.
Is it possible to achieve something like this in Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (hacky) by putting the following code into a file "clone_git_repository.yaml"

```
- block:
  - name: Clone git repository
    git:
      repo: "{{ project_gitlab_repository }}"
      dest: "{{ project_build_path }}"
    async: 120
    poll: 5
  rescue:
  - set_fact:
      retry_count: "{{ 0 if retry_count is undefined else retry_count | int + 1 }}"
  - fail:
      msg: maximum retries reached
    when: retry_count | int == 5
  - command: "rm -rf {{ project_build_path }}"
  - include_tasks: clone_git_repository.yml
```

Not very elegant but apparently this is the way to go until you can specify retries for a block.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `retry` is not supported for blocks. I've just run into the same issue and I figured out another hacky way. Instead of using the ansible `git` module run it by the `command` module and you can solve the retrying in the command. Not very nice, but I still prefer this way then the "include_task" solution (and in my case I already had the `command` statement). Also if you need more than 3-5 retries it gets quite messy this way.

in your case it would look like this:

```
- name: Clone git repository
  block:
  - command: "git clone {{ project_gitlab_repository }} {{ project_build_path }} || 
              sleep 5 &&
              git clone {{ project_gitlab_repository }} {{ project_build_path }} ||
              sleep 20 &&
              git clone {{ project_gitlab_repository }} {{ project_build_path }}"
    async: 120
    poll: 5
  rescue:
  - file:
      path: "{{ project_build_path }}"
      state: absent
  - ansible.builtin.command: /bin/false
```